# Android NDK pathing error when compiling SDL2 library

Tags: macos, android-ndk, sdl-2, eclipse-adt

If I copy the SDL source folder inside the jni folder of the android project, the SDL2 library builds correctly, but when I try to reference the same SDL folder from the filesystem (outside of the project) the console throws:

[armeabi] Compile thumb  : main <= SDL_android_main.c
In file included from /Library/SDL/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c:4:0:
/Library/SDL/src/main/android/../../SDL_internal.h:34:24: fatal error: SDL_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "SDL_config.h"

The SDL_config.h file exists and the path is correct.

The Android.mk file is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := main
SDL_PATH :=/Library/SDL
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c \
main.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: I solved this indirectly creating a dynamic link in the jni folder to the SDL one in the filesystem: ln -s /library/SDL ./SDL and then in the Android.mk file: SDL_PATH :=../SDL

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved indirectly creating a dynamic link in the jni folder to the SDL one in the filesystem:

```
jni: ln -s /library/SDL ./SDL
```

Then in the Android.mk file:

```
SDL_PATH :=../SDL
```